# multiple components in same page in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

Good morning,

I've been learning Angular 5 and despite of all the new stuff, there is something that I can't realize how to be done yet.

In the past I studied AngularJS, so I'm triying to understand Angular 5 and seeing how the framework has changed,

Currently I'm dealing with a simple thing that I could do in Angular JS, multiple controllers per page, something like this.

```
<div class="widget" ng-controller="widgetController">
    <p>Stuff here</p>
</div>

<div class="menu" ng-controller="menuController">
    <p>Other stuff here</p>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to do it in Angular 5 because so far I only find examples and code relatet to a component-per page.

Maybe it is a very simple answer, but I will really apreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

super simple :)

Instead of labeling each element with a controller, you create custom component instead.

```
<widget></widget>
<menu></menu>
```

you can declare a custom component by doing the following...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  template: `<div> stuff goes here </div>`
})
export class MenuComponent  {

}
```

Angular docs have a tutorial call tours of heros, and it goes in depth into angular.

https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's very simple !

Here it is :

```
<app-widget></app-widget>
<app-menu></app-menu>
```

In Angular, you create components that will replace the tags that match their selectors.